# Square numbers ???

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Let a, b natural numbers such that $ab+1 | a^2 + b^2$ . Prove that $(a^2 + b^2)/(ab+1)$ is a square number.
I've tried a few things but it's getting me nowhere and it's annoying. Please help.

Comment: Could you sketch some of the non-working things you've tried?

Comment: I only tried messing around with some basic calculations

Comment: Where did you get this problem for? It looks like an olympiad question

Comment: @kingW3 It is a notorious olympiad problem.

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate. Thank you